# How do pass an object(double in this case) from fragment to public class?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

My situtation is that I am able to get the latitude and longitude in the onCreate of my Fragment. What I want to do is then send those values to my Sun public class but my attempts show that the those values are zero in the Sun Public class. My logcat shows however that those values are being generated in my fragment. This tells me that my location code does work , I just get those values into my public class.

Therefore, my question is whether there a way to send those values to a public class from a fragment or is it possible that the instance being called in my onCreateView is being called before the longitude and latitude are generated in onCreate? If that is the case is there a way to get the longitude and latitude values first before onCreateView is generated. Basically I need the location from the fragment to put in a calculation in my public sun class.The location in bold. From my understanding onCreate is generated before onCreateView I'm not sure why this would be the case.  Here is my code:

**Fragment**

```
    public class TestFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);


    requestPermission();

    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getActivity());

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)  {

        return;
    }
    mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(getActivity(), new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {

            if (location != null) {
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                longitude = location.getLongitude();

                System.out.println("This is latitude:" + latitude);
                System.out.println("This is longitude:" + longitude);



            }

        }
    });


    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);



    }




}

private void requestPermission(){
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),new String[]{ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    Sun sunInstance = new Sun();
    sunInstance.SunmCalculation();

 return view;
```

**Public Class Sun**

```
    public class Sun {
    private double M = 356.0470 + 0.9856002585 * PlanetVariableCalculations.getd2();
    private double w =  282.9404 +  4.70935e-5 * PlanetVariableCalculations.getd2();

  public void SunmCalculation() {
    if (M < 0) {
        while (M < 0) {
            M = M + 360;
        }

    } else if (M > 360) {
        while (M > 360) {
            M = M - 360;
        }
    }

    double L = w + M;
    SunSidereal(L);

}

private void SunSidereal(Double L){
     double Ls = L;
    double RAhours = 300;
    double GMST0 = Ls/15 +12;
    double SIDTIME = GMST0 + UTCValues.getutcComplete() + **Longitude**/15;
    double HA = SIDTIME - RAhours;

    System.out.println("This is SIDTIME:" + SIDTIME);
    System.out.println("This is HA:" + HA);
    System.out.println("This is the longitude: " + Longitude  );

}
```

}

Comment: Is this the whole Sun class ?

Comment: Not all of it. I can put it all of it in if it would help. Its all calculations I didnt want in the main thread so I thought having all of it wouldn't actually contribute to the problem.

Comment: The code you posted is not indicative of the solution you want, because there is no constructor of the class Sun, so how would a Sun object be created to use its methods? And how would these methods have access to the values you want to pass?

Comment: I added the entire Sun class.

Comment: You want to pass `latitude` and `longtude` to the Sun class right? What is the Sun class supposed to do with these values?

Comment: See my answer_.

Comment: The Sun class is supposed to take the longitude value from the fragment and calculate the SIDTIME. How the code works is that the Fragment provides the Longitude. I want that passed to the Sun Class and the Sun class will take the L calculated in SunmCalculation AND Longitude provided by the fragment and use those values in SunSidereal. Let me know if this is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the method signatures in the class like this:

```
public class Sun {
    private double M = 356.0470 + 0.9856002585 * PlanetVariableCalculations.getd2();
    private double w =  282.9404 +  4.70935e-5 * PlanetVariableCalculations.getd2();

    public void SunmCalculation(Double longtitude) {
        if (M < 0) {
            while (M < 0) {
                M = M + 360;
            }

        } else if (M > 360) {
            while (M > 360) {
                M = M - 360;
            }
        }

        double L = w + M;
        SunSidereal(L, longtitude);
    }

    private void SunSidereal(Double L, Double longtitude){
        double Ls = L;
        double RAhours = 300;
        double GMST0 = Ls/15 +12;
        double SIDTIME = GMST0 + UTCValues.getutcComplete() + longitude / 15;
        double HA = SIDTIME - RAhours;

        System.out.println("This is SIDTIME:" + SIDTIME);
        System.out.println("This is HA:" + HA);
        System.out.println("This is the longitude: " + Longitude  );
    }
}
```

You can create an object of the class `Sun` inside `onSuccess()`:

```
Sun sun = new Sun();
```

and call its `SunmCalculation()` method like this:

```
sun.SunmCalculation(longitude);
```

Comment: This does it. Thanks.